# Remote connection to SQL in MS access gets calculating state

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have 2 machines which locate in same network. In first is running SQL Server 2014  Express and in second is running a MS Access application which uses the database.

But the problem is if I start MS Access, the first form loads successfully but application is very slow. I have a lot linked tables is MS Access which use database. At the bottom of window has state "Calculating..".

Currently i have allowed remote connection to SQL. I have disabled firewall on the SQL Server machine. I have tested connection via telnet from machine 2 to the SQL Server machine and it was successful.

So what am I missing that my connection via MS Access fails? Can there be some user permissions (but telnet connection was successful)? Is it possible to debug MS Access somehow why the connection is slow?

Comment: I take it it stays in the "calcuating" state? I suggest you open it, holding down SHIFT, which stops any autoloading stuff. If it gets past calculating, go to your tables and see if they open. I'm guessing you have a badly performing macro or something in your open form.

Comment: Indeed, *Calculating...* in status bar involves form controls. On form, check for complex DLookups and complex queries for recordsources in comboboxes/listboxes/subforms, form filtering/ordering, and OnOpen/OnLoad events